# Creating and destroying elements as opposed to showing and hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a dynamic page that involves moving elements from one place to another. At the moment I am removing the elements from their source location and then creating them at their destination using a bunch of `document.createElement()` and `document.appendChild()` calls. These elements have a bunch of event listeners, which I have to then re-assign every time I modify the DOM in this way.

For performance reasons I am starting to think it would be best to have the elements stay right where they are and just be hidden and shown as they are 'moved'. I can't use jQuery's `appendTo()` method for other reasons.

Comment: What sorta reason would it be that you can't use `appendTo`? I believe it's just a fancier `appendChild` Use `$('whatever').before(<div></div>)`

Comment: I can't use the appendTo method because the styling of the elements changes when I move them

Comment: Ok, I see. What's happening there is the styles that belong to the parent you are appending to is being inherited by the element you are moving. If you actually make a MCVE (**M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we could help you properly. Please post JavaScript/jQuery, CSS, and HTML that would be relevant to your question. Use [Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Comment: Well, no I want them to change. I only want to take certain parts of the element over, which I am manually copying and reconstructing. My question is more about the performance of hiding/showing VS destroying/constructing

Comment: It's a matter of what you feel comfortable with. On a small to even medium scale application, there shouldn't be any discernible difference in speed (at least to a human's perception). Honestly, there's not enough code for me to say, "Hey, there's a better way to do that". Btw, there are ways to keep your event listeners on dynamic elements.